# How to change the brightness of an Video or Image using UISlider on run time (Click Camera) in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, xcode4.5

```
-(IBAction)changeslidervalue:(id)
   {
      imageView.alpha = sliderValue.value;
   }
```

I am using this code, can anyone help me or solve my issue..

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: are you getting any value from the slider?

Comment: NO If you are open the camera then you change the brightness your device as like brightness setting in your device.I am using UISlider for change the extra Brightness on our device as a run time..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the screen brightness instead of changing the videos alpha?

Try this code:

```
-(IBAction)changeslidervalue:(id)
{
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:sliderValue.value];
}
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks !this code is working but after choose image on library.If you are open the camera then you change the brightness your device as like brightness setting in your device.I am using UISlider for change the extra Brightness on our device as a run time..

Comment: I am using UISlider for change the extra Brightness on our device as a run time its possible?

Answer (score 0):

Apple developer have one demo GLImageProcessing for images related processing. You can find it here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html. Import your image here and after processing you need to save it again in image view. Actually this demo is working with OpenGL ES api.
(If this demo is use full for you comment here,i will provide you code for change EAGLView to image view)